# Android ScrollView does not show bottom content in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, scrollview

I started a new Tabbed Activity project in Android Studio. The fragment content does not show the last Control 'Serial Number'. Below the fragment xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ibrahimnehme.slidingtab.StockTakeFragment">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/part_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Part Number"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/part_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Part Description"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="3"
                 />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lotId"
            style="@style/InputLabel" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/LotId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:prompt="@string/lotId"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:padding="5dp"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/Location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Location"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/SubLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Sub Location"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/nsn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="NSN"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/Unit_Of_Measurement"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Unit Of Measurement (UoM)"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/ControlId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Control Id"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/Ext_Trace_Id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Ext Trace Id"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/ExpiryDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Expiry Date"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/Status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Status"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/Serial_Number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Serial Number"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The last visible control is 'Status'. I tried to PadBottom="20dp" then I wrap the ScrollView with the RelativeLayout but still have the same issue.

Minimum SDK API 23 Android 6

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the contents of your fragment in different xml file and then include it in your fragment xml file and use The NestedScrollView instead

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.ibrahimnehme.slidingtab.StockTakeFragment">

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <include layout="@layout/yourOtherXMLFile"/>

  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you remove padding in thet android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

```css
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/Serial_Number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Serial Number"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
```

remove  **android:paddingBottom="20dp"**

Comment: add android:marginBottom="20dp" thet will be help you

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:fillViewPort="true"`
so

it becomes

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ibrahimnehme.slidingtab.StockTakeFragment">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewPort="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/part_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Part Number"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/part_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Part Description"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                     />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lotId"
                style="@style/InputLabel" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/LotId"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:prompt="@string/lotId"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/Location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Location"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/SubLocation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Sub Location"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/nsn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="NSN"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/Unit_Of_Measurement"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Unit Of Measurement (UoM)"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/ControlId"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Control Id"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/Ext_Trace_Id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Ext Trace Id"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/ExpiryDate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Expiry Date"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/Status"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Status"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/Serial_Number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Serial Number"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I had the same problem. Adding [`fillViewPort`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport) making the scrollview to fill its view.